# Implementation of MySQL’s PASSWORD() Function in Java

Tags: java, php, mysql

Hello
I am looking for a way to produce the same result as with MySQL's PASSWORD function in Java.
There are a Implementation of MySQL’s PASSWORD() Function in Java code?

For example:

Password: 123
in MySQL PASSWORD ('123 ') -> *23AE809DDACAF96AF0FD78ED04B6A265E05AA257

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the answer pointed to by @ypercube, MySQL PASSWORD() is just sha1, applied twice.

Using [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils.html):

```
public static String MySQLPassword(String plainText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] utf8 = plainText.getBytes("UTF-8");
    return "*" + DigestUtils.shaHex(DigestUtils.sha(utf8)).toUpperCase();
}
```

**EDIT:** tested, added throws clause, uppercased and a prefix "*".

---

**Working code (to replace shaHex() that was not working):**

```
public static String MySQLPassword(String plainText)
                  throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    byte[] utf8 = plainText.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] test = DigestUtils.sha(DigestUtils.sha(utf8));
    return "*" + convertToHex(test).toUpperCase();
}
```

Comment: You are missing the leading `*`.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work I get the following Exeption: 05-05 10:43:25.392: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(29427): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex.encodeHexString

Comment: @user I don't know much about Android, but it seems like you might have to do the conversion to hex yourself. Just use `sha` instead of `shaHex`, and wrap it with your own function the converts `byte[]` to a hex String.

Comment: If I you use only "sha" 
I get: [B@4637d2e0

And I use then my own convert
I get: PWHash: 40bd001563085fc35165329ea1ff5c5ecbdbbeef

But it should be this: 23AE809DDACAF96AF0FD78ED04B6A265E05AA257

it's not the same

Comment: @user: Did you apply `sha()` twice?

Comment: no.

byte[] utf8 = plainText.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] test = DigestUtils.sha(utf8);

return convertToHex(test);

Comment: Try with `test = DigestUtils.sha(DigestUtils.sha(utf8)); return convertToHex(test);`

Comment: Thanks so much this is it:

PWHash: 23ae809ddacaf96af0fd78ed04b6a265e05aa257

I don't know why DigestUtils.shaHex() doesn't work? It should be make the same or?

Comment: This is the working code:

public static String MySQLPassword(String plainText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] utf8 = plainText.getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[]test = DigestUtils.sha(DigestUtils.sha(utf8));
    return "*" + convertToHex(test).toUpperCase();
}

with CONVERT Byte to String from the link of the first answer

Comment: @user: You can accept itsadok's answer so other know that it was the most helpful.

Comment: @user you should upvote ypercube's answer as well. @ypercube thanks for picking up my slack :)

Answer (score 2):

Updated [**itsadok**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5894536/) a bit.

```
public static String MySQLPassword(String plainText) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        byte[] utf8 = plainText.getBytes("UTF-8");
        return "*" + DigestUtils.sha1Hex(DigestUtils.sha1(utf8)).toUpperCase();
    }
```

Comment: This one both works and doesn't use the depricated sha and/or shaHex functions

Answer (score 1):

This question is almost the same - replace "Java" with ".NET or MS-SQL-Server" :

**[simulating-mysqls-password-encryption-using-net-or-ms-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868482/simulating-mysqls-password-encryption-using-net-or-ms-sql)**

It will give you an idea of how to convert MySQL `PASSWORD()` function into Java.

---

Please note that `PASSWORD()` purpose is for MySQL internal use and other, more secure methods should be used for hashing and authentication in application code. Unless you are limited somehow to use this one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where `MessageDigest` used, plus converting to HEX string. So, just use it.

http://www.anyexample.com/programming/java/java_simple_class_to_compute_md5_hash.xml

Comment: The methode 
private static String convertToHex(byte[] data) { ... }
is perfecktly, when shaHex() doesn't work

Thanks