# Using MySQL PASSWORD() with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

We have an old MySQL database that has passwords stored using the MySQL function PASSWORD(). Is there a way using Entity Framework in C# to select the row with the password?

The old way would be to do a sql query

```
SELECT * FROM `employees` WHERE `id` = @id AND `password` = PASSWORD(@pword);
```

The @id and @pword are then passed to the .Net Connector as parameters.

In Entity we do this

```
var query = from employeeRow in context.employees 
            where employeeRow.id.Equals(username_txt.Text) 
            select employeeRow; 
_foundEmployee = query.SingleOrDefault();
```

But this will return the row data without checking the password. How would I check the password that has been hashed with MySQL PASSWORD()?

Comment: *“The `PASSWORD()` function is used by the authentication system in MySQL Server; you should **not** use it in your own applications.”*

Comment: I agree SNOWFLAKE, but I can't do anything about that at this point. I just have to use what I got while I'm updating the software. I will eventually get the chance to update the database and at that point I'll change over to a local hashing method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
where employeeRow.id.Equals(username_txt.Text) && employeeRow.password.Equals(hashedPassword)
```

You need to do password hashing separately. I'd suspect mysql documentation will tell you what algorithm PASSWORD() method uses.

Comment: I agree that we should be doing password hashing separately. I'm in the process of updating this old software, but until I can get it fully updated I have to work with the existing data. It was built using the PASSWORD function built into MySQL, so I have to use it for now. I'll look and see if I can find the method they use in MySQL and see if I can duplicate it in my code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/868482/simulating-mysqls-password-encryption-using-net-or-ms-sql might help you. From your question I understood that you didn't understand why it's returning the whole row without checking password -> I showed you why, so I really don't understand the downvote.

Comment: That link was very helpful. It was exactly what I was looking for. I understand what you were saying with your answer. But I didn't know how to convert to a hash from c# without using a MySQL query "SELECT PASSWORD('someString')" to get the users input into the hash that needs to be tested. I was thinking there was a way to do it directly with Entity Framework, but hashing local using info from that link will work great.